# Google Maps API key for websites market

Tags: google-maps

Just a one quick question..Ive created a google map using my API key..But what if I create a map for an application, Should I used my own google api key or not.??

Anyone??Got a good advice?

Comment: I made the end user provide the API key

Comment: do you have some side of server - side script to work with?

Comment: For server side..I used PHP and MySql with local server wamp or xamp..

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need some server side script to be able to store the user provided password.

Your confusion is probably actually loading the key since it is needed to be included in the script `src` tag.  I will show you an example of both.

First some type of server side code to get the stored API_Key, you don't need to use asp c#..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string API_KEY;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Load your API key from wherever you stored it on the server (This ones from W3 Schools)
        API_KEY = "AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM";

    }
}
```

Use your API Key to dynamically include the script source tag.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">


<script type="text/javascript">
        var api_key_string = '<%= API_KEY %>';
        var fileString = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + api_key_string + "&sensor=false"
        var sourceString = "<script src=\"" + fileString + "\" type=\"text/javascript\"><\/script>";
        document.write(sourceString);

</script>

<script>

    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
  , mapProp);
    }



   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Hello thank you.....I dont really get the first box code..Is that an ASP?? I dont have experienced on ASP as I only work on PHP..Is there a way to do it on PHP?

Comment: @JuanDev sorry Im not quite the PHP guy, perhaps you can re-tag your question and someone can help us out! You just need to retrieve your API key from MySql table, if that's the route you want to go, and populate it into API_KEY variable with PHP, so you can set the api_key_string javascript variable.

Comment: No worries..Thanks for the help..Anyways, using the Google map Api Key..Do I have to create my own to used on an application if I want to sell it on the market or just a default one.Just like those 3rd party google map plugin?

Comment: I have always made the end user (customer) provide the API key.  That way, usage is not tied to you (the developer) but the customer.